# Adding header values in Filter to use as Action parameters in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use Windows Authentication with my application and have a `UserInfo` table in my database to store information about the user. I keep the `UserId` for this table in the user's Session. Dealing with the Session and its extension methods is causing problems with Unit Tests, so I wanted to stop using it in Controller Actions.

I tried reading it from the Session and adding it to Request Headers in a filter:

```
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        Controller controller = (Controller)context.Controller;

        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("userId", context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId"));
    }
```

Then using `[FromHeader]` to get the value in Actions that need it:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction(Guid? id, [FromHeader]string userId)
    {

    }
```

But the problem is the `userId` parameter here is always `null`. I can see the `userId` value when debugging if I inspect `HttpContext.Request.Headers.Unknown` though.

Comment: What if your client adds an arbitrary `userId` header to its requests? I don't think it's a good idea to rely on client input to retrieve something as basic as user info. Why not rely on `Controller.User` or `HttpContext.User`?

Comment: Aside from my previous comment, you can push your desired value into the `userId` action parameter using `context.ActionArguments["userId"] = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId")`

Comment: I was going to add a check for an existing `userId` header value and remove it first once I got this working. I like the `ActionArguments` idea though.

Comment: `Controller.User` doesn't have this information since its from a separate database table. I authenticate using Windows Auth, not Identity.

Comment: There are ways to make it work properly using `User` or `Authenticaiton`. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x.

Comment: `User` works and is accessible, its just a `WindowsPrincipal` object with AD information. I haven't found a way to stash extra information in it such as their Profile Id which is an issue I've struggled with.